# Using a delegate in a QtableView to show an icon

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, delegates, qtableview

I would like to implement a delegate in a QTableview for showing an icon next to the text, what class or function should I implement ?

Comment: [Star Delegate Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and set your own delegate class  to your view widget which inherits  from  [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) (such as `QColumnView`, `QTableView` and so on) via [setItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) method.

Here is an simple example which use this mechanism to render a color block before color name with `QTableWidget`.

in `main.cpp`

```
#include "QTableWidget"
#include "delegatedemo.hpp"
#include <QApplication>
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QTableWidget tableWidget(10, 1);
QStringList headerLabels;
headerLabels << "color";
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerLabels);
tableWidget.setItemDelegate(new iconItemDelegate);
tableWidget.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

in `delegatedemo.hpp`

```
#ifndef DELEGATEDEMO_HPP
#define DELEGATEDEMO_HPP

#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
class iconItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
iconItemDelegate(QWidget* parent = 0)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}
void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
            const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QColor color(index.data().toString());
    QRect cellRect = option.rect;
    int cH = cellRect.height();
    QRect colorIconArea(QPoint(cH * 0.25, cellRect.y() + cH * 0.25),
                        QSize(cH * 0.5, cH * 0.5));
    if (color.isValid()) {
    painter->fillRect(colorIconArea, QBrush(color));
    painter->drawText(QPoint(cH, cellRect.y() + cH * 0.75),
                        index.data().toString());
    }
}
};
#endif // DELEGATEDEMO_HPP
```

The final result like this

[image: Delegate Demo]

If you want show an icon, just let the `paint` method in your custom delegate class paint an icon.