# How to change position of QIcon In QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I want to set Icon next to text in QTableWidgetItem.

I tried initStyleOption of styledItemDelegate. It's set at the end of the qtablewidgetitem.

[image]

```
def initStyleOption(self, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index) -> None:
    if index.column() == 0:
        option.decorationPosition = QStyleOptionViewItem.Right
    return super().initStyleOption(option, index)
```

But I Want to this example.

[image]

if I want to that QIcon set  next to text when I click QpushButton in QTableWidgetItem, what shuld I do?

↓ My Test code :

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 500, 500)

        # QTableWidget
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(400, 400)

        # QIcon
        self.icon: QIcon = QIcon("pencil.png")
        self.icon2: QIcon = QIcon("Check.png")

        # pushButton
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(450, 450, 50, 50)
        self.button.setText('Edit')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.markItem)
        self.show()

        for i in range(3):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(i)
            for j in range(2):
                if j == 1:
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(self.icon2, '0'))
                else:
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(QIcon(), f"{i * 58}"))

    def setIcon(self) -> None:
        tableWidgetItem: QTableWidgetItem = self.tableWidget.currentItem()
        col = tableWidgetItem.column()
        if col == 0:
            tableWidgetItem.setIcon(self.icon)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The alignment is based on the absolute geometry of the item, not the display contents. If you want to show the icon right next to the text, you need to implement your own custom item delegate and consider the size required by the text.

Comment: Can I get an  litte bit example?

Comment: Sorry but that's not how StackOverflow generally works: we don't just "give you the code", especially when its implementation may be as complex as it could be like in this case: there are many ways to achieve what you want, and they may differ *a lot*. A possible option could be to implement a delegate that paints a QTextDocument and also include the icon using base64 encoding for the icon. I'd suggest you to take your time to do some research on the above subjects and attempt to achieve what you want, then eventually [edit] this question with those attempts in case you didn't succeed.

Comment: yes. I get it. The question is wrong. I'll have to work hard. Thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: The official [Star delegate example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html) is a good start. Googling shows examples such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923137/custom-qstyleditemdelegate-to-draw-text-with-multiple-colors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574028/using-a-delegate-in-a-qtableview-to-show-an-icon).